# Is my HDD about to die ? (Erratic benchmark results)

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata, benchmarking

From a live USB I got the following results from a hard drive benchmark tool :

[image: Benchmark result]

- The partition is the first out of 3 from a 1TB SATA WD-blue drive, used as storage (no OS running from it).
  I have repeated the test 4 times and always got the same curve, as well as an unusually long testing time. The other partitions have a "normal" looking curve.
- I've previously had trouble with that HDD, which I was trying to fix : couple of days ago I noticed accessing files would "freeze" the disk, generating a 100% saturated access queue with barely no data transfer. I followed these steps :

  - Run chkdsk / file system check from windows' safe mode : failed and made the disk inaccessible, freezing the system at the "welcome" screen.
  - Deleted partition table from live USB Ubuntu to unlock Windows
  - Ran Western Digital's tool diagnostic from Windows : SMART and extended clusters tests told me the disk was healthy
  - Used partition eraser tool to write zeroes on the whole disk : no i/o errors.
  - Created new partitions : disk recognized, boot successful, writing and reading about 100MB of mp3 files didn't cause any errors.
  - Ran the benchmark test from the live USB, and got the results above.

The original problems seem to have appeared after I got many system crashes and forced reboots (mistakes using Blender). I don't know if that's possible but I would think these repeated have damaged the part of the drive giving these fluctuating performances.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I mentioned I did that already with "Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows" from Western Digital's website, and all was green. I used the tools mentioned in the links you gave and I got the same results :
http://hpics.li/62c651b
And
http://hpics.li/d57f903

Comment: The SMART results show the drive is healthy, and that's what counts. Erratic performance may have many reasons, but it's not an indication that the drive is about to fail.

Comment: All right, that's a good point, but then have you any idea on how I could understand the reason for this localized lack of performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good thing that you've tested the HDD with our tool and since it's saying that the drive is healthy.

However, I've noticed a couple of bad sectors detected (the C5 - Current Pending Sectors count in the RAW S.M.A.R.T. values) which could be causing these benchmarks, but it's not a reason of concern at the moment, like the DLG tool confirmed.

With that said, you can keep using the drive IMO, but also make a regular backups of your data on another location and keep an eye for any increase of this parameter in particular. In case such an increase occur, feel free to [contact our support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=36HL1Q) so a RMA could be arrange if the hard disk is still under warranty.

Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I think I won't try my luck any more with that drive, after all the mess I've been through because of it. So I will contact the company that sold me the PC and see what they can do.